# Javascript Opener Object Doesn't Work Anymore

Tags: javascript

For years, I have used the following code to execute functions on a window's opener:

```
if(opener) {
    opener.location.href=opener.location;
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working anymore.  I tried using parent but that doesn't seem to work either.  How can I get this to work again?

Comment: Interesting ... did something change in your application code otherwise?

Comment: is the opener object null ? did you try debugging ?

Comment: Well is it a different domain? What opened the window?

Answer (score -1):

window.opener is null, can you try parent.window.opener?

Comment: I believe I got it figured out.  When using window.open, I have the opener object.  If the window was opened via <a href> and target was set to _blank, opener is null. I could have sworn that pages opened that way was always providing the opener object but perhaps not.  It's easy enough for me to change my links to use window.open.